# Compiling sdl linux project for android

Tags: android, c++, linux, sdl

I have a simple c++ sdl project which compiles fine for linux. I need to compile it for android without changing the source code (like in qt). When I tried to compile it using documentation, I had following error: 
"jni/src/../SDL/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c:62: error: undefined reference to 'SDL_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status".
Can anyone give me working example that can be compiled both for linux and android?

Comment: Is it possible to list your Android makefile? Also, when you mentioned a documentation, can you list which documentation did you follow?

Comment: @share I used android makefile from sdl's "android-project" directory. Documentation I used is "docs/README-android.md" file.